# PHP permissions

Tags: php, database, permissions, apache2

I try to execute the following line of code:

```
$dbh = dba_open("./data/products", "c", "gdbm") or die("Couldn't open database");
```

Unfortunately, I get the die.

I think something is wrong about the permissions here. I've set the permissions of the directory of the script to "0777" and the owner of the directory to "www-data" (I'm working with apache2). I don't know what information else could be useful to solve the problem.

Edit: I'm attempting to create the database. It doesn't exist before the execution of the line.

Edit2: I've also tried the absolute path:

```
$currentDir = getcwd();
$dbh = dba_open("$currentDir/data/products", "c", "gdbm") or die("Couldn't open database");
```

Edit3: Error log.

```
[Fri Feb 15 18:20:37 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Feb 15 18:20:41 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  dba_open(./data/products,c): No such handler: gdbm in /var/www/phpTraining/listing12.1.php on line 14
```

Comment: what about permissions on the DB file itself? having access to a directory doesn't mean you have access to the file.

Comment: What happens if you use the full path instead of a relative path?

Comment: If the file already exists, try setting the mode to `w`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the error_logs for more clues.